# Difference registered user from guest on login

Tags: unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

Im using Unity3D and SmartFoxServer to develop a multiplayer game.

I want that players can register (Im using sign up assistance from SmartFoxServer), so they can login an play. But also, that they can play as guest players.

I enabled this feature in the admin, but when I made a LoginRequest in the client, if the user doesn't exists (or the password is wrong) I'm logged in as Guest.

I need a command for registered users login and one for guest players login or a way to tell SmartFoxServer to difference between a registered user login, and a guest login. There is some built in solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

Implement a customhandler for the login event

```
//Inside your main extension
addEventHandler(SFSEventType.USER_LOGIN, UserLoginEventHandler.class);
```

---

```
public class UserLoginEventHandler extends BaseServerEventHandler{

@Override
public void handleServerEvent(ISFSEvent event) throws SFSException {

String loginName = (String) event.getParameter(SFSEventParam.LOGIN_NAME);

//send a blank username as login for guest, smartfox will create a guest user for you
if(loginName.isEmpty(''))
return 

//Authenticate your registered user here

if(...isNot Authenticated..)
{
SFSErrorData errData = new SFSErrorData(SFSErrorCode.LOGIN_BAD_USERNAME);
errData.addParameter(loginName);
// Fire a Login exception
throw new SFSLoginException("UserName/password not correct", errData);
}
}
}
```